# Programmatically create forms in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to ask the user how many points he wants to create and then get each points coordinates.

I tried creating a initial text field to get how many points and then a loop to create each form. It works but I don't know how to get each form value.

How can I get each form values? Or is there a better way to do it?
[image]

```
   <template>
      <div>
        <v-card class="mb-3">
          <v-card-text>
            <v-text-field label="How many nodes" :value="nodes" @input="onInput" type="number"></v-text-field>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <template v-for="i in nodes">
              <v-flex :key="i" xs12 md3>
                <div>
                  <v-card class="mb-3">
                    <v-card-text>
                      <div>Node {{i}}</div>
                      <v-text-field label="Coord X" value="x1" @input="getValues" type="number" v-model="no1"></v-text-field>
                      <v-text-field label="Coord Y" :value="y1" @input="getValues" type="number"></v-text-field>
                    </v-card-text>
                  </v-card>
                </div>
              </v-flex>
            </template>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        data () {
          return {
            nodes: 2
          }
        },
        methods: {
          onInput (val) {
            this.nodes = parseInt(val)
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a better way of doing it:

```
   <template>
      <div>
        <v-card class="mb-3">
          <v-card-text>
            <v-text-field label="How many nodes" v-model="nodes" type="number"></v-text-field>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <template v-for="(node, index) in nodesArr">
              <v-flex :key="i" xs12 md3>
                <div>
                  <v-card class="mb-3">
                    <v-card-text>
                      <div>Node {{index + 1}}</div>
                      <v-text-field label="Coord X" v-model="node[index].coordX" type="number" v-model="no1"></v-text-field>
                      <v-text-field label="Coord Y" v-model="node[index].coordY" type="number"></v-text-field>
                    </v-card-text>
                  </v-card>
                </div>
              </v-flex>
            </template>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        data () {
          return {
            nodes: 0,
            nodesArr: []
          }
        },
        watch: {
            nodes(newVal) {
                this.nodesArr = [];
                for(var i=0; i<this.nodes; i++){
                    this.nodesArr.push({coordX: "", coordY: ""});
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Whats going on:

1. Set  up a `v-model` on the input which takes the number of nodes and bind it to `nodes` property.
2. initialized a new property `nodesArr : []` which will be used to loop through to display each Coord input
3. set up a watcher on `nodes` which loops through the number of nodes entered and pushes those many objects `{coordX: "", coordY: ""}` to `nodesArr` array
4. we loop through `nodesArr` using `v-for="(node, index) in nodesArr"` to display the inputs for x-coord and y-coord
5. The x-coord input is bound to the corresponding `coordX` property making use of the `index` we get in `v-for`
6. Similarly the y-coord  input is bound to the corresponding `coordY` property making use of the `index` we get in `v-for`
7. since the inputs are two way bound using `v-model` you have all the input data in `nodesArr` property which can be used as you wish